# How to create a module which installs entity types from /config/install/….yml files?

Tags: paragraphs

I created lots of paragraphs which go with a theme. Everything works fine, and now I want to deploy this theme and the related paragraphs to several more sites. I exported the entity-types (node,paragraphs and fields) using the config manager UI. I then stripped the UUID from the .yml files and put them into modules/custom/MY_MODULE/config/install. I then created the MY_MODULE.info file.

```yaml
name: fTheme
description: paragraph types for f theme
type: module
core_version_requirement: ^9
package: Custom
dependencies:
  - paragraphs:paragraphs
```

Now I'm stuck.
I simply have no clue as what to put into MY_MODULE.module to trigger the entity-type creation at install. Searching the web and reading three books didn't help. I'm using Drupal 9.4 and it seems there were lots of changes since 8.0 (which all my books are based on). Thanks in advance to point me to the proper spot (for dummies).

Answer (score 1):

To let Drupal use the files in the config/install directory to create entities or configuration objects, you don't need any code in the module file, or even have a module file. You just need to have a .info.yml file (not a .info file); that is all Drupal needs to know that a directory contains a module and use those files to create entities / configuration objects.

That is true in Drupal 8, as well as Drupal 9.

As example of what a Drupal core module does, see the *Forum* module, which uses the content of its [*config/optional*](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/tree/9.4.x/core/modules/forum/config/optional) directory to create entities. Its [`forum_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21forum%21forum.install/function/forum_install/9.4.x) hook just creates the taxonomy term it used.

```php
function forum_install($is_syncing) {
  // Set the weight of the forum.module to 1 so it is loaded after the taxonomy.module.
  module_set_weight('forum', 1);

  // Do not allow to delete the forum's node type machine name.
  $locked = \Drupal::state()
    ->get('node.type.locked');
  $locked['forum'] = 'forum';
  \Drupal::state()
    ->set('node.type.locked', $locked);
  if (!$is_syncing) {
    // Create a default forum so forum posts can be created.
    $term = Term::create([
      'name' => t('General discussion'),
      'description' => '',
      'parent' => [
        0,
      ],
      'vid' => 'forums',
      'forum_container' => 0,
    ]);
    $term->save();
  }
}
```

The difference between the *config/install* and the *config/optional* directories is explained in [Optional configuration provided by modules and themes is now stored in config/optional](https://www.drupal.org/node/2453919).

Comment: I recall somebody told me that using the *config/optional* directory would not throw errors when a module is uninstalled and installed again. If I remember correctly, in that case, when the *config/install* directory is used, Drupal would complain the created entity already exists.

Comment: The info.yml + /config/install/*.yml solution works like a charm, thank you very much. And yes, when the files are in /install, I get notified … Have yet to find the switch to remove entities when the module gets de-installed, or whatever procedure might be appropriate.

Comment: If you put the files in the *config/optional* directory, that is done automatically from Drupal. (That is what I recall.)

Comment: If you look at the content of [core/modules/forum/config/optional/node.type.forum.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.4.x/core/modules/forum/config/optional/node.type.forum.yml), you will notice there aren't dependencies that could not be met. It defines a content type with an enforced dependency on the Forum module (which contains that configuration file). The enforced dependency is what makes Drupal remove that entity when the module is uninstalled. (That is what I recall.)